# iOS MDM policies

Tags: ios, mdm

I need to prepare a presentation on iOS Mobile Device Management.  I have been asked to include the policies that are implemented and choose one of the and describe it in detail. The problem is, I don't know what are the different policies that exist. Please help me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following is the list of Configurations & Queries you can make to the device, if you had installed custom configuration on it. These queries can be made by MDM

Supported configurable items

Accounts
• Exchange ActiveSync
• IMAP/POP Email
• Wi-Fi
• VPN
• LDAP
• CardDAV
• CalDAV
• Subscribed calendars

Passcode policies
• Require passcode on device
• Allow simple value
• Require alphanumeric value
• Minimum passcode length
• Minimum number of complex characters
• Maximum passcode age
• Time before auto-lock
• Passcode history
• Grace period for device lock
• Maximum number of failed attempts

Security and privacy
• Allow diagnostic data to be sent to Apple
• Allow user to accept untrusted certificates
• Force encrypted backups

Supervised only restrictions
• Allow iMessage
• Allow Game Center
• Allow removal of apps
• Allow iBookstore
• Allow erotica from iBookstore
• Enable Siri Profanity Filter
• Allow manual install of Configuration Profiles

Other settings
• Credentials
• Web clips
• SCEP settings
• APN settings
• Global HTTP Proxy (Supervised only)
• Single App Mode (Supervised only)

Device functionality
• Allow installing apps
• Allow Siri
• Allow Siri while locked
• Allow Passbook notifications while locked
• Allow use of camera
• Allow FaceTime
• Allow screen capture
• Allow automatic syncing while roaming
• Allow syncing of Mail recents
• Allow voice dialing
• Allow In-App Purchase
• Require store password for all purchases
• Allow multiplayer gaming
• Allow adding Game Center friends

Applications
• Allow use of YouTube
• Allow use of iTunes Store
• Allow use of Safari
• Set Safari security preferences

iCloud
• Allow backup
• Allow document sync and key-value sync
• Allow Photo Stream
• Allow shared Photo Stream

Content ratings
• Allow explicit music and podcasts
• Set ratings region
• Set allowed content ratings7

Querying Devices

In addition to configuration, an MDM server has the ability to query devices for a variety of information. This information can be used to ensure that devices continue to  comply with required policies.

Supported queries

Device information

• Unique Device Identifier (UDID) 
• Device name 
• iOS and build version 
• Model name and number 
• Serial number 
• Capacity and space available 
• IMEI 
• Modem firmware 
• Battery level
• Supervision status

Network information

• ICCID 
• Bluetooth® and Wi-Fi MAC addresses 
• Current carrier network 
• Subscriber carrier network 
• Carrier settings version 
• Phone number
• Data roaming setting (on/off)

Compliance and security information

• Configuration Profiles installed
• Certificates installed with expiry dates
• List all restrictions enforced
• Hardware encryption capability
• Passcode present

Applications

• Applications installed (app ID, name, version, size, and app data size)
• Provisioning Profiles installed with expiry dates

Comment: thanks a lot... where can I get more info on the passcode policies?

Comment: @user2155715 Check this link : http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/it-center/deployment-mdm.html Please accept the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 11):

Here are the link for everything you need to know about MDM and around MDM.

**Over-the-Air profile delivery concept**

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/OTASecurity/OTASecurity.html

**MDM**

(This one requires access to Apple Enterprise Developer Program)
http://adcdownload.apple.com//Documents/mobile_device_management_protocol/mobile_device_management_protocol.pdf

Reverse engineered MDM protocol:

http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf

**Enterprise Deployment guide**

http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_guide.pdf

**Configuration profiles guide**

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html

*Update 1*

Here is exameple how allow game center works. Let say you have a device enrolled in MDM.

- At some moment MDM server decides that you (your device) should be diasslowed to run game center (as example it's your enterprise policy).
- MDM server generate a Install Configuration  Profile command and put it in the queue of pending commands for your device.
- MDM server sends push notification to your device
- Your device receives push notification and contacts back to MDM Server
- Your device requests for any outstanding commands
- Your device receive a command Install Configuration Profile. As part of this command, you it gets a profile which contains Restriction payload.
- This restriction payload will have a key allowGameCenter with value false
- Your Device will save this configuration profile
- A user will be prohibited from running Game center thereafter.

Comment: thanks... can you please guide me on how a particular policy works? eg; the policy workflow for "allow game center"

Comment: @user2155715: Please see the update. Let me know, if you have more questions.